# Removing decimal seconds from time format data in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, time

I've got two large df's from two xlsx spreadsheets and would like to merge them 'on' time stamp ['Time'] data.

The problem is that one data set has recorded time to decimal seconds and the other to whole seconds. This means that the two data set ['Time'] keys never match up...

```
df1     Time                                 df2     Time
0       00:07:53.755000                      0       00:07:53
1       00:07:54.096000                      1       00:07:54
2       00:07:55.097000                      2       00:07:55
3       00:07:56.099000                      3       00:07:56
4       00:07:57.002000                      4       00:07:57
5       00:07:58.012000                      5       00:07:58
```

I've tried modifying time formats in Excel but it always retains the millisecond value because of its fractional 24 hour thing. I need to remove the decimal seconds from df1 (or just get them to match somehow!) to allow matching with row data from df2 and am hoping there is a much simpler way to do this in python?

Thanks to any and all advice!

Comment: Do you want to round or truncate? Can you just merge based on the index?

Comment: Preferably truncate but either is fine. I can't use index as the instrument recording one set of these time stamps periodically skips one or two seconds. The data is from two instruments synced to UTC and outputting GPS location. I just want to use the time stamps to match their relative locations at time x. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way to do this.

```
# convert time to str and remove millisecond
df1['Time'] = df1['Time'].astype(str)
df1['Time'] = df1['Time'].str.replace('\..*','')

# Just to be sure there are no error because of timeformat
df2['Time'] = df2['Time'].astype(str)

# now we can join
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Time')
```

Answer (score 7):

In `df1`, you can just set microseconds to 0:

```
df1['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Time']).apply(lambda x: x.replace(microsecond=0))
```

Then perform your merge as normal.

Answer (score 3):

I would use pandas `strftime`

```
df1['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Time']).dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
df2['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Time']).dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')

merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Time')
```

Comment: I tried this and I get error:

raise AttributeError("Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike "

AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Comment: Looks like you don't have datetime values. You can first use the `to_datetime` function. I'll update my answer.